# Chrome Dev Tools not showing pending ajax requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have been using chrome dev tools for ajax debugging for quite a long time now.
Recently I noticed that pending asynchronous ajax calls aren't shown anymore in the Network tab; they are shown just after completion. 
Can't tell precisely when I started noticing this, but surely in the last 2 months. 
Using Firebug I get the same result on Chrome, but it works instead on Firefox.

I also disabled all the extensions on Chrome but nothing changed.

So I ask, has anybody else run into this issue with chrome dev tools and solved it? has it something to do with recent versions of chrome? maybe something in the way it deals with async calls has changed?

Comment: Actually i've never seen, that chrome had pending status for xhr requests. But i'm always missing this feature after switching from firefox.